# Any way to break only if another break is encountered in Visual C++ 2008?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, breakpoints

I have found myself in this situation many times where I need to break into a function that is called hundreds of times only after a particular break-point has been hit.

So let's say there is a function that updates the status of objects. This is called multiple times per 
frame. I am testing a function that edits an object. As soon as that function is hit, I can then break into the `UpdateStatus` function. Obviously, if I put a breakpoint in `UpdateStatus` it will always break and I will never be able to interact with the program. What would be great if I could set a condition on the breakpoint to only break if the breakpoint in the other function hit. Note that this is just an example.

I am using Visual C++ 2008.

Comment: If one breakpoint is hit, can't you then manually set or activate another breakpoint?

Comment: So once the first break is hit do you want the second break to always keep triggering or only trigger once until the first break is hit again?

Comment: Right-click the breakpoint and select either Hit Count or Filter, whatever is appropriate in your case.

Comment: @DavidThornley: Yes, I can, but that becomes really cumbersome after a few debugging sessions (remove breakpoint in `UpdateStatus` and then put it back in and so on)

Comment: @VictorT.: Only trigger once after the breakpoint in the other function has hit (only then will `updatestatus` update the status of the object I am interested in, otherwise, it is updating thousands of objects)

Comment: @Samaursa don't remove the breakpoint, disable it.  Every breakpoint has a checkbox in the breakpoints panel to quickly enable and disable it.

Answer (score 2):

I remember running into a situation like this myself. I believe you can combine Visual Studio tracepoints with Visual Studio macros to do this pretty easily. This page describes how to write a macro that turns on breakpoints: http://weseetips.com/tag/enable-breakpoint/ Since you want to enable only a single breakpoint,  you'll want to use some combination of file and line number in your macro to enable only the breakpoint you want--you can find the breakpoint object members here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.breakpoint.aspx (File and FileLine look particularly useful)

This page describes how to use a 'tracepoint' to run a macro: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/232dxah7.aspx (This page has some nice screenshots of setting up tracepoints: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/18/debugging-tips-with-visual-studio-2010.aspx in VS2010)

So you could create a macro that will enable your breakpoint, and create a tracepoint that executes your macro. (You can even add a second tracepoint that disables the breakpoint afterward, so that you can easily repeat the process.)

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to place a [conditional breakpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sye83ce.aspx) within the `UpdateStatus` itself.

Alternatively, place a conditional breakpoint at the call-site of `UpdateStatus` then perform the step-in manually.

Whether you'll be able to do one or the other (or any at all) depends on how complex the breakpoint condition is and whether input for that condition is "reachable" from the particular stack frame.

Answer (score 1):

You could have the first breakpoint set a flag when hit, then let the second breakpoint check that flag as a condition.
You can set the flag by specifying a "message" to be printed when hit, like so:

```
{flag = 1;}
```

`flag` needs to exist in the scope, of course.
(It would be nice if it was possible to declare a variable that only exists during the debug, but I'm unaware of how to do this.)